# store date in structure after strtok() a string line from a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to use strtok() on a string line and puts its element into a structure elements 
but i can't write the correct code ...please any help

> this is the main

```
store book;
char line[80];
printf("Insert book as:'title','author','publisher','ISBN','date of publication',and'category'\n");
gets(line);
char *p;
char s[2]=",";
p=strtok(line,s);
```

> the struct

```
typedef struct bookStore{
    char title[80];
    char author[80];
    char ISBN[20];
    char date[20];
    int numOfCopy;
    int currNumOfcopy;
    char category[20];
}store;
```

Comment: You didn't describe the expected behavior and the behavior that you actually get. Also, you will need to call strtok more than once.

Comment: i already wrote my code but it didn't work ...so my mainly question is how to put data into a struct after strtok my line

Answer (score 1):

## Struct

You printf the following:

```
printf("Insert book as:'title','author','publisher','ISBN','date of publication',and'category'\n");
```

and yet your struct says nothing about publisher.

Also it contains two fields which are 80 chars long and 3 fields, which are 20 chars long, and yet you allocate only 80 chars buffer for the string you want to parse.

## gets

This is one of the functions, that exists in C by mistake. It should never be used, because it makes your program vulnerable to stackoverflow (the security problem, not this site;) ).

Here's the right way to fill in your line variable.

```
  fgets(line,80,stdin);
```

## strtok

You call it with the input string to get the first token, like you did, and then you need to call it with NULL instead of the input string to get the next token. You will know, that there are no more tokens in the string when it returns NULL.

This function keeps internal state using static variable, which is a bad practice. This practice should be avoided in most cases.

## Populating your struct

You can do it using strcpy for strings, you will need to `#include<string.h>`

```
  p=strtok(line,s);
  length = strlen(p); /* length should be declared int where you declare your variables */
  if (length > 79) {
    printf("You entered title which is %d characters, but 79 were expected", length);
    exit(1);
  }
  strcpy(book.title, p); /* It's safe, because we already checked the length of the string */
}
```

If you need to populate a number, you will have to use sscanf

```
  int number;
  sscanf(p,"%d", book.numOfCopy);
```

Comment: thanks alot .. you give me a big help :) I have a project to deliver ;)